# Bash scripting Shakespeare Insult generator

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to make an insult generator by reading in from a file and outputting a phrase. The file ("myfile" has 3 columns of insults and I want the output to read "thou art a (insult1) (insult2) (insult3)"

what I have so far....

```
while read line 
do

Column1=$(cut -d" " -f 1)    
Column2=$(cut -d" " -f 2)
Column3=$(cut -d" " -f 3)

Insult1=${Column1[word]}
Insult2=${Column2[word]}
Insult3=${Column3[word]}

echo "Thou art a" $Insult1 $Insult2 $Insult3
done < myfile
```

I'm very close with this, I just don't have "Thou art a" At the beginning of every phrase, just the first one. It's reading through all of the insults before it reaches the end of the string.

Comment: What you have so far is not a serious attempt, is it? It looks a little like a camouflaged "please write my code".

Comment: Could you take a gander now perhaps?

Comment: Does myfile has line-endings? What do you get when you enter `head -1 myfile1`, just the first line or all insults?

Comment: just the first line  "artless base-court apple-john"

Answer (score 1):

The shell is perfectly capable of splitting input on whitespace.  (Getting it *not* to do that can be a challenge!)

```
while read first second third; do
    echo "Thou art a $first $second $third"
done <myfile
```

Of course, this is just `sed 's/^/Thou art a /' myfile` in disguise.  If you want to include some sort of random selection, I would suggest organizing the input differently -- perhaps three different files, or a single file with three sections.

```
first=$(shuf -n 1 adjectives.txt)
second=$(shuf -n 1 adjectives.txt)
third=$(shuf -n 1 nouns.txt)
echo Thou art a $first $second $third
```

(This has a small possibility of getting the same adjective twice.  Maybe it's not even a problem, if thou art a dirty dirty dog.)